# Windows 7 Home Premium cannot connect to internet via wireless or ethernet connections

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ipv6, ipv4

I have an HP laptop and I cannot connect to the internet even though it says "Internet Access". When I try I get "Cannot access page", then the browser closes and searches for a solution that results a "There was a problem and Internet Explorer closed". This happens with both Wifi and Ethernet connections. I have disabled and enabled the drivers, no change. I checked the IPv4 and IPv6 connectivity status and IPv4 says connected, but IPv6 says No Internet Access. I checked IP addresses and IPv4 has all the addresses needed, but IPv6 has none. I have it set up to configure automatically. I'm wondering if this is the reason why I cannot connect, and if so how do I find the IPv6 address, DNS and preferred gateway information and configure it manually.

Comment: The first thing to try in these situations is another browser.  If that works, the problem is with IE.  If it doesn't, then start diagnosing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

All that you have described leads me to believe that you do have internet access. There are a couple of more things you can do to troubleshoot your problem.

1. try pinging a public address such as 4.2.2.2 and if you get responses for each ping the problem is likely to be with the DNS address you are using, or the web browser. As an example IE 11 does have its share of problems and as such chrome, firefox, or safari might be better alternative to use for internet browsing.

My suspicion is with Internet Explorer. I am one of those who cannot connect to any website using IE without getting the same error you defined IE is closing due to a problem.

Hope this leads you to a successful outcome....